# How to position button in gridpane cell

Tags: javafx

I'm using gridpane and have positioned different objects in cells.
I tried to position one botton to the right in cell

```
Button lisaTabelisse = new Button("Lisa tabelisse");
    GridPane.setConstraints(lisaTabelisse, 0, 5);
    lisaTabelisse.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);,
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to position like that?

Answer (score 1):

The [`setAlignment()` method defined in `Button`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setAlignment(javafx.geometry.Pos)) (which you are calling with `lisaTabelisse.setAlignment(...)`) determines how the text (and graphic, if you have one) are aligned *within the button itself*. Unless you take steps to change it, the button will be sized to have just enough space to hold the text (and graphic), so there will be no additional space within which to move the content. So typically, this won't have any effect. However, if you manually increase the size of the button (or do something else, like setting parameters on the `GridPane` so that it fills the entire cell), you'll see the text right-aligned within the button.

If a cell in a `GridPane` has more space than it needs to hold the elements placed in it, you can change the positioning of the element within the cell using the `static` methods [`setHalignment`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHalignment(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.HPos)) and [`setValignment`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setValignment(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.VPos)) degined in `GridPane`. So the code you need to achieve what you want is

```
GridPane.setHalignment(lisaTabelisse, HPos.RIGHT);
GridPane.setValignment(lisaTabelisse, VPos.CENTER);
```